# Get the row ID within an SQLiteDataReader

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is it possible to get the `rowid` of the record when using `"SELECT * from table"`? Does the SQLiteDataReader class have a way of doing that internally?

Currently I can only read the `rowid` if I use `"SELECT rowid, name, description from table"`.

I then use `GetValue(0)` to then read the `rowid`.

Comment: The datareader can only give you the values that you've selected. The `rowid` is not included as long as you don't select it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I solved it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick for me!

> SELECT rowid, * from table

According to [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter), the datareader can only give you the values that you've selected. But I don't know the column names of the table, so by appending `rowid` to `*` we get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Why the downvote? You don't understand the question or what?